# Point Re-Plot on Image Rescaling

Tags: image, plot, point, rescale

I want to be able to plot a point on a rescaled image back to the original image and still point at the same location on the image.

Say I have an image with an original size of 1024x768.  I rescale it to fit into a viewable zone of 640x480 and plot a point at (x=300, y = 212).

When I view the image back at its original 1024x768, what formula would I use to plot the point?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know what scale your scaled image is,

Thats

```
 scale = (size of scaled image) / (size of original image)
```

once you have the scale you can simple translate original coordinate to scaled coordinates by multiplying by the scale.

```
 scaled_x = original_x * scale_x
```

The go from the scaled coordinates to original its simply a division by the scale.

```
 original_x = scaled_x / scale
```

If the scaling hasn't kept the aspect ration of the image ( not a problem in your case ) you will need to workout the x and y scales separately

This looks like homework to me so I'll let you substitute in the numbers.

Comment: Ok - perfect - thanks a bunch - I'll employ this to see if it jives!

Thanks!